# OOP - How to pass data "up" in abstraction?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, software-design

I have run into a problem when designing my software.

My software consists of a few classes, `Bot`, `Website`, and `Scraper`.

`Bot` is the most abstract, executive class responsible for managing the program at a high-level.

`Website` is a class which contains scraped data from that particular website.

`Scraper` is a class which may have multiple instances per `Website`. Each instance is responsible for a different part of a single website.

`Scraper` has a function `scrape_data()` which returns the JSON data associated with the `Website`. I want to pass this data into the `Website` somehow, but can't find a way since `Scraper` sits on a lower level of abstraction. Here's the ideas I've tried:

```
# In this idea, Website would have to poll scraper. Scraper is already polling Server, so this seems messy and inefficient
class Website:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scrapers = list()
        self.data = dict()

    def add_scraper(self, scraper):
        self.scrapers.append(scraper)
   
    def add_data(type, json):
        self.data[type] = json

    ...
```

```
# The problem here is scraper has no awareness of the dict of websites. It cannot pass the data returned by Scraper into the respective Website
class Bot:
     def __init__(self):
          self.scrapers = list()
          self.websites = dict()
```

How can I solve my problem? What sort of more fundamental rules or design patterns apply to this problem, so I can use them in the future?

Comment: Some object must call scrape_data, and some object must know the connections between Scrapers and Websites.  So why doesn't the object that calls scrape_data just pass the returned data to the correct Website object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you start talking about a many-to-many parent/child relationship, You should be thinking about compositional patterns rather than traditional inheritance. Specifically, the Decorator Pattern. Your `add_scraper` method is kind of a tipoff that you're essentially looking to build a handler-stack.

The classic example for this pattern is a set of classes responsible for producing the price of a coffee. You start with a base component "coffee", and you have one class per ingredient, each with its own price modifier. A class for whole milk, one for skim, one for sugar, one for hazelnut syrup, one for chocolate, etc. And all the ingredients as well as the base components share an interface that guarantees the existence of a 'getPrice' method. As the user places their order, the base component gets injected into the first ingredient/wrapper-class. The wrapped object gets injected into subsequent ingredient-wrappers and so-on, until finally `getPrice` is called. And each instance of `getPrice` should be written to first pull from the previously injected one, so the calculation reaches throughout all layers.

The benefits are that new ingredients can be added without impacting the existing menu, existing ones can have their price changed in isolation, and ingredients can be added to multiple types of drinks.

In your case, the data-struct being decorated is the `Website` object. The ingredient classes would be your `Scrapers`, and the `getPrice` method would be `scrape_data`. And the `scrape_data` method should expect to receive an instance of `Website` as a parameter, and return it after hydration. Each Scraper needs no awareness of how the other scrapers work, or which ones to implement. All it needs to know is that a previous one exists and adheres to an interface guaranteeing that it too has a `scrape_data` method. And all will ultimately be manipulating the same `Website` object, so that what gets spit back out to your `Bot` has been hydrated by all of them.

This puts the onus of knowing what Scrapers to apply to what `Website` on your `Bot` class, which is essentially now a Service class. Since it lives in the upper abstraction layer, it has the high-level perspective needed to know this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is, taking inspiration from noded structures, to have an atribute in the `Scraper` class that directly references its respective `Website`, as if I'm understanding correctly you described a one-to-many relationship (one `Website` can have multiple `Scrapers`). Then, when a `Scraper` needs to pass its data to its `Website`, you can reference directly said atribute:

```
class Website:
     def __init__(self):
         self.scrapers = list()   #You can indeed remove this list of scrapers since the 
                                   #scrapper will reference its master website, not the other way around
         self.data = dict()  #I'm not sure how you want the data to be stores, 
                             #it could be a list, a dict, etc.
     def add_scraper(self, scraper):
         self.scrapers.append(scraper)

     def add_data(type, json):
         self.data[type] = json

class Scraper:
     def __init__(self, master_website):
         #Respective code
         self.master = master_website  #This way you have a direct reference to the website.  
                                       #This master_website is a Website object
     ...
     def scrape_data(self):
          json = #this returns the scraped data in JSON format
          self.master.add_data(type, json)
```

I don't know how efficient this would be or if you want to know at any moment which scrapers are linked to which website, though

Comment: Isn't having this two-way association between "parent" and "child" objects bad practice?

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was just buildig from its proposal. Only case I see a two-way association beneficial is if it is necessary to know at any moment all the parsers associated to a specific website. But yeah, you could remove the atribute self.scrappers all together